# What happens if the professors that write your letter of recommendation have the same name?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter, personal-name

So there are two professors at my university that have the same name (the only differences are their titles), and incidentally they both know me well enough to write my letter of recommendation, and I also have no other option. Does this affect my application?

Edit: Thank you all for your answers! They have the exact same name and this is confusing even for student at the school, and may I add even their title are kinda similar (one is Assoc. Prof., doctor in clinical psychology and the other is doctor in psychology).

Comment: They share both first and last names?

Comment: Are they closely related, or is this just coincidence?

Comment: Statistically this has to happen on occasion. There are a lot of Smiths in the world. Also Lees and Wangs and Nguyens.

Comment: Do they have the same first, middle, and last name ?

Comment: Ah, yes, the possibility of sock-puppet letter writers! :)

Comment: For those with a Unix background, there were two people named Stephen R. Bourne working at Bell Labs at the same time in the same hallway so this is not a unique situation. One link [here](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/~jnw/SysAdminfa01/Lectures/26.html)

Comment: Did you not say it yourself? "Their titles…" should do it. Apropos of which, who would accept a reference from a name alone, without a title?

Comment: As someone who has both an evil twin *and* a nearly identically named non-related person in the neighborhood, I can sympathize with you and especially with the two professors.

Comment: Since it's academia, they should include their ORCIDs after their names.

Answer (score 31):

Clearly, this situation is prone to cause confusion.
However, you should be able to easily avoid this of by informing whoever processes your application in an appropriate space, e.g.:

- > Please note: The authors of both my recommendation letters happen to be named *Alex Smith.* This is coincidence; they are distinct persons.
- > Recommendation letters: Alex Smith (astrochelionologist), Alex Smith (theoretical lepidopterologist).

I cannot imagine that anybody would even subconsciously hold this against you as long as they know what the situation is.
If anything, it makes your application more memorable.

The only exception I can think of is if the two professors are related or married, in which case somebody might consider them not sufficiently independent, but then again many professors at the same department are not completely independent either.
(Mind that I do not consider this a valid reason to consider your application less good, just something that others might think.)

Comment: Dang, I see I studied the wrong thing in grad school. Wow, astrochelionologist.

Comment: The astrochelionologist is presumably an experimentalist.

Comment: Paleoastrochelionologist.

Comment: Quantum Paleo...

Comment: "The authors of both my recommendation letters happen to be from..." -- either say the *authors* happen to *be*, or the *letters* happen to be *from*.

Comment: @nanoman: What can I say? I rolled back the edit that introduced this.

Comment: @Buzz: See the above.

Comment: @nanoman, both authors have a parent named Alex Smith.

Comment: It seems that an astrochelionologist is a [real thing](https://blogs.nasa.gov/kennedy/2018/05/16/nesting-sea-turtles-depend-on-dark-skies/)

Comment: @paulgarrett "quantum paleo" just sounds like a new fad diet

Comment: @Wastrel: Astrochelionoligsts are those who study [this being](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discworld_(world)#Great_A'Tuin).

Answer (score 5):

I would say it won't affect your application in any way.

Certainly, the professors would include their titles along with contact info such as phone numbers and emails in their letters of recommendation.

Now, as you mentioned that their titles are different, that would suffice.

Comment: That leaves open the possibility of a single person with two appointments